# How to pass a system property to gradle with the jenkins gradle plugin?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, system-properties, bintray

I have a gradle tasks that deploys some stuff to bintray using curl.

For this to work it needs my bintray api key. I don't want to put that in my build script (or a property file) since all this stuff is hosted in plain sight at github.

Instead I made the task use a property named `bintrayApikey` which is to be provided when calling gradle. When I run it locally using

```
gradlew pushToBintray -DbintrayApikey=<my api key>
```

everything works as intended.

So the next step is to make this work from my Jenkins over at cloudbees. Since there doesn't seem to be a special place for putting system properties I just added them to the tasks, but this does not seem to work. In the console I can see it is accessing bintray all right, but then finishes with:

```
This resource requires authentication
```

So how can I provide the property value in my jenkins job configuration?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `-Pmyprop` instead of `-Dmyprop`.

The Gradle Jenkins Plugin accepts parameters with `-P`.

`-D` is for java parameters.

Comment: Thx that worked! Can you give a hint to why it works, or especially why -D works locally but not on the jenkins?